# Google forms - Multiple choice OR checkbox - other regular expression

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-forms

This is not a RegEx building question.
Is there an option to add RegEx validation to the "other" option in either the multiple choice or the checkbox question type?
In other words, users would be able to select a set option OR they would be allowed to add their own option ("other"). This own option should meet the regex.
I cannot find such an option via the form design tool but was wondering if this is possible via the script.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is currently not supported.*

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for Google Forms use and functionality, and that you would like to request they implement it.

You can do this by visiting https://forms.google.com, clicking the hamburger menu (`≡`) in the top-left-hand side of the page, selecting `Help & Feedback`, and then finally `Send feedback` in the dialog that appears on the right. Filing this request here ensures that it goes to the correct team for the feature idea.